# Llamar al controlador en SpringMVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc

necesito llamar a mi controlador directamente cuando se arranque la aplicación,para pintar el html con los datos, pero no sé como se hace ->

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>

<!--
Most controllers will use the ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping above, but
for the index controller we are using ParameterizableViewController, so we must
define an explicit mapping for it.
-->
<bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
        <props>
             <!-- Spring -->
            <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>

            <!-- Funciones del Sistema -->
            <prop key="Form_CrearCuenta.htm">SistemaController</prop>
            <prop key="CrearCuenta.htm">SistemaController</prop>
            <prop key="Cerrar_sesion.htm">SistemaController</prop>
            <prop key="Corregir_Examen.htm ">SistemaController</prop>


            <!-- Funciones Comunes de usuarios-->
            <prop key="Home.htm">UsuarioController</prop> 
            <prop key="Login.htm">UsuarioController</prop>
            <prop key="Hacer_examen.htm">UsuarioController</prop>

            <!-- Funciones Comunes Administrador-->
            <prop key="AdministrarUsuarios.htm">AdminController</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>


<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
      p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
      p:suffix=".jsp" />

<!--  The index controller.   -->
<bean name="indexController"
   class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
   p:viewName="index" />

<!--  Controlador del Sistema  -->
<bean name="SistemaController" class="Controladores.ControladorSistema"/>

<!--  Controlador del usuario  -->
<bean name="UsuarioController" class="Controladores.ControladorUsuario"/>

<!--  Controlador del admin  -->
<bean name="AdminController" class="Controladores.ControladorAdministrador"/>
```

Se poner formularios que llaman a controladores y reenviar los datos a una página y pintar los datos, pero llamar directamente a mi controlador cuando arranque mi programa, estoy teniendo problemas.

Intenté hacer

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="SistemaController" />
```

Pero no consigo hacerlo,gracias.

Comment: No entiendo lo que quieres hacer, ahí tienes una lista de *asociaciones* para que Spring sepa que responder cuando se le pida un recurso con una determinada URL.

Comment: saludos @PabloLozano, Quiero que cuando se lance la aplicación, en vez de llamar al index directamente, se vaya a un controlador, (yo hay saco de la base de datos x datos) y YO reenvío al index con los datos.

Comment: ¿Al iniciar la aplicación? ¿No es un servidor?

Comment: Nada más mostrarse la página tenga unos datos que vienen de un servicio rest, esta es la página principal "index". Entonces había pensado que cuando "cargase" se llamase a un controlador por defecto y hago lo que tenga que hacer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahora mismo tienes que la página por defecto de tu aplicación sea gestionada por el bean `indexController`

```
<prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>
```

Que es una instancia de `ParameterizableViewController`

```
<bean name="indexController" 
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
    p:viewName="index" />
```

Podemos ver [en la documentación de Spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/ParameterizableViewController.html) que es una clase Controller básica, creada para simplemente asociar una vista:

> Trivial controller that always returns a named view.

Puedes, por tanto, crear una clase nueva (llamada por ejemplo `IndexController`) que obtenga toda la funcionalidad que quieres añadir, y que muestre la vista (el JSP) que necesites, mostrando los datos que quieras:

```
<bean name="indexController" class="controladores.IndexController" />
```